# Show clicked image from flickr with tags and comments AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, flickr

I have to make app for listing recent photos from Flickr with option when click on any image to show that image with tags and comments it contains.

I've made this:

**core.module.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('flickrApp.core', ['ui.router', 'ngResource']);

})();
```

**core.factory.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('flickrApp.core')
    .factory('flickrImgs', flickrImgs);

flickrImgs.$inject = ['$http'];

function flickrImgs($http) {

    var url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=415028ef16a31ed8f70f9dc3e90964d1&extras=url_q,url_o,tags&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

    var photos;

    var factory = {
        getPhotos: getPhotos
    };

    return factory;

    function getPhotos() {
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            factory.photos = response.data.photos.photo;
        });
    }
};
})();
```

**core.controller.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('flickrApp.core')
    .controller('flickrController', flickrController);

flickrController.$inject = ['flickrImgs', '$location', '$http'];

function flickrController(flickrImgs, $location, $http) {

    var fc = this;

    fc.showImg = function (id) {
        $location.path("/photos/" + id);
        console.log(id);
    };

    flickrImgs.getPhotos().then(function () {
        fc.photos = flickrImgs.photos;
    });

}

})();
```

**core.router.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('flickrApp.core')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/core/header.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('main.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/core/home.html',
                    controller: 'flickrController',
                    controllerAs: 'fc'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('main.singleImg', {
            url: '/photos/:id',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/core/single-img.html',
                    controller: 'flickrController',
                    controllerAs: 'fc'
                }
            }
        });

    newPhoto.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'flickrImgs'];

    function newPhoto($stateParams, flickrImgs) {
        return flickrImgs.get({
            id: $stateParams.id
        }).$promise;
    }

}

})();
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div ng-repeat="photo in fc.photos | limitTo:16" class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <a href ng-click="fc.showImg(photo.id)">
        <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{photo.url_q}}" width="100%">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

**single-img.html**

```
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div ng-repeat="photo in fc.photos | filter : {id: photo.id} | limitTo: 1" class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <a href ng-click="fc.showImg(photo.id)">
        <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{photo.url_o}}" width="100%">
    </a>
    <div>Tags:
        <button class="btn-primary">
            {{photo.tags}}
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>Comments:
        <div>
            {{photo.comments}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I click on image listed on home page, I want to pass that image to single-img.html template and I get image id in url, but I don't know how to pass it to html.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing ui-sref in  in home.html

```
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div ng-repeat="photo in fc.photos | limitTo:16" class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <a ui-sref="main.singleImg({id: photo.id})">
        <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{photo.url_q}}" width="100%">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

// Updated flickrImgs factory method

```
function getPhotos() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (factory.photos) {
        deferred.resolve(factory.photos);
    } else {
        $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
            factory.photos = response.data.photos.photo;

            deferred.resolve(factory.photos);
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

// single image state with new controller

```
.state('main.singleImg', {
    url: '/photos/:id',
    views: {
        'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/core/single-img.html',
            controller: 'singleImgController',
            controllerAs: 'sic'
        }
    }
});
```

// New Controller

```
angular
    .module('flickrApp.core')
    .controller('singleImgController', singleImgController);

singleImgController.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'flickrImgs'];

function singleImgController($stateParams, flickrImgs) {
    var vm = this;

    flickrImgs.getPhotos()
    .then(function(photos) {
        angular.forEach(photos, function(photo) {
            if(photo.id == $stateParams.id) {
                vm.photo = photo;
            }
        })
    });
}
```

// New single-img.html

```
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{sic.photo.url_o}}" width="100%">
<div>Tags:
    <div class="btn-primary">
        {{sic.photo.tags}}
    </div>
</div>
<div>Comments:
    <div>
        {{sic.photo.comments}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I forgot ui-sref, thank you for that. But, still in single-img.html, I don't get the proper image.

Comment: Muthukannan Kanniappan Yes, that helps, I get the id of the photo but am I able to pass url_o parameter so I could use it in the img tag? I'm little confused, sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Most of it is updated :-) Would suggest you read more on $q and ui-router.

Comment: Muthukannan Kanniappan Thank you very much. You're very kind! Only edit I would do is to single-img template: <div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{vm.photo.url_o}}" width="100%"> <div>Tags: <div class="btn-primary"> {{vm.photo.tags}} </div> </div> <div>Comments: <div> {{vm.photo.comments}} </div> </div> </div>

Comment: Thanks one more time! ;)